# Handling Push notifications in android using GCM and Django

Tags: android, django, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to android programming, there are two types of push notifications in my app (for eg- one for Notices and other for News), how can I differentiate these notifications and how can I open different activities by clicking them separately?

```
Random random = new Random();
int notifyID = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            if (ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY.equals("message")) {
                sendNotification("Notice: " + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
            }
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NoticeActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_icon);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("You've received a new message.")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    /* Notification Icon as per API level*/

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_s);
        //    mNotifyBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon);
    }

    // Set pending intent
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    // Set the content for Notification
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(msg);
    // Set autocancel
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this functionality, you have to generate 2 different Notification with different notification ids.

Let me explain

*Define two int variable for notification id.*

```
final int NOTIFICATION_NOTICE = 0;
final int NOTIFICATION_NEWS = 1;
```

See below code.

For NOTICE Notification

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent noticeIntent = new Intent(context, NoticeActivity.class);   // Activity Name as you want to Open on click

noticeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        noticeIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_NOTICE, notification);   // Notification id for differentiate Notification
```

For NEWS Notification

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent newsIntent = new Intent(context, NewsActivity.class);     // Activity Name as you want to Open on click

newsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        newsIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_NEWS , notification);     // Notification id for differentiate Notification
```

**EDIT**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

   final int NOTIFICATION_NOTICE = 0;
   final int NOTIFICATION_NEWS = 1;
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            if (ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY.equals("message")) {
                sendNotification("Notice: " + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY), extras.get("notificationType"));
            }
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg, String type) {

    if(type.equalsignoreCase("Notice")){
     NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
     NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

     Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NoticeActivity.class);
     resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
     PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

     Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_icon);

     mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
     int defaults = 0;
     defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
     defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
     defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


     mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("You've received a new message.")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(defaults);
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    /* Notification Icon as per API level*/

      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_s);
        //    mNotifyBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
      } else {
        mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon);
      }

    // Set pending intent
     mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_NOTICE, mNotifyBuilder.build());
  } 
  else if(type.equalsignoreCase("News")){
     NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
     NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

     Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);
     resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
     PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

     Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_icon);

     mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
     int defaults = 0;
     defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
     defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
     defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


     mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("You've received a new message.")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(defaults);
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    /* Notification Icon as per API level*/

      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_s);
        //    mNotifyBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
      } else {
        mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon);
      }

    // Set pending intent
     mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_NEWS , mNotifyBuilder.build());
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Should i make two different classes for news and notices with _extends IntentService_ ? and how my backend will acknowledge that which notification is for what purpose?

Comment: No need to create 2 different class. You use Push Notification right ? then you have some input(notification value/data) to show on notification bar. Its your ability to put extra values with push notification to differentiate notification type as notice or news. and get the value in android and show notification as base on the value.

Comment: I can't get you like this. Should i upload my code, so that you can tell me the changes to be made?

Comment: @ShubhamChugh see my edit.  get an extra from intent to identify the notification type.

Comment: Ok.. i'll try this and get back to you in a while

Comment: As user @ViramP says. Please send first `notificationType` with push notification and then get the type in android.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to integrate GCM in your android app.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Here,
No need to two Push notification class or methods.

Discuss with your web team and tell them give new key in which they will give you notification type.(ie. Notice or News)

i.e
{type = "Notice",message =" My message"};

And

{type = "News",message =" My message"};

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by using this trick-

```
if (ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY.equals("message")) {

                    String strNotification = ("" + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
                    String arr[] = strNotification.split(" ", 2);
                    String firstWord = arr[0];
                    System.out.println("string: " + firstWord);

                    if (firstWord.equalsIgnoreCase("NOTICE:")) {
                        sendNotification("" + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
                    } else if (firstWord.equalsIgnoreCase("NEWS:")) {
                        sendNotificationNews("" + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
                    }

                }
```